# How can I set a video in a loop in MobileVLCKit?

Tags: ios, swift

`VLCMediaPlayer` has no member `repeatMode` While `VLCMediaListPlayer` has repeat mode.

I'm currently setting as

`mediaPlayer.repeatMode = VLCRepeatMode.repeatCurrentItem`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `mediaList` and play the first media

```
let media = VLCMedia(url: url)

let mediaList = VLCMediaList()
mediaList.add(media)

let mediaListPlayer = VLCMediaListPlayer(drawable: mediaPlayerView)
mediaListPlayer.mediaList = mediaList

mediaListPlayer.repeatMode = .repeatCurrentItem
mediaListPlayer.play(media)
```

`mediaPlayerView` is the view where de video will play